# how to login multiple website by one account?

Tags: javascript, php

I got a question about my project.What they want me to do is:

1)Our school has 3 login panel like one of them is for library, other one is for student info and more something like that.

2)So basically, my user information which are id and password is same for all of them.( All the login panel that school has)

3)And they want me to do is to code a script to create one login panel in order to log in all of them.

Is it possible to do? And i do not know where to start? Thank you!

Comment: Yes it is possible, try doing some google. you will definitely get some help.And if you stuck in that, post again we will happy to help you out. :)

Comment: You can do it with `select box` to chose which site they want to login.

Comment: I tried a lot times to google it. thats why im asking you guys:).

Comment: @Ulucay what exactly was what you googled?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you want to do is SSO (Single sign-on), google this and you will obtain a lot of informations about it

Comment: "thanks" thats what i want.

Comment: If you have any particular problems feel free to post a new topic about what you are facing

Comment: thank you! let me understand to concept first about SSO :)